# Passing Memory-Optimized Table Into Inline Function Causes Error When Called From Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

When I use a memory-optimized table with a stored Procedure that passes the table to an inline table-valued function I get an error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
>   Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>   Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64)
>      Apr 27 2017 17:36:12
>      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>      Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

I can recreate the error like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Name] AS TABLE
( [Name] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED )
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)

GO

CREATE TABLE Table1
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
, [Data] nvarchar(max) not null
)

INSERT INTO Table1 ([Data])
VALUES (N'blah1'), (N'blah2'), (N'blah3'), (N'blah4')

GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Test
( @table dbo.[Name] READONLY
) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
JOIN @table t2
    ON t2.[Name] = t.[Data]
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test2
  @table dbo.[Name] READONLY
AS

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test(@table)

GO

DECLARE @memTable dbo.[Name]

INSERT INTO @memTable ([Name])
VALUES ('blah1'), ('blah3')

EXEC dbo.Test2 @memTable
```

Sometimes this happens and sometimes it doesn't. I have other procedures that work similarly and usually they work fine.

I get this dump in my `ERRORLOG` (Cut short for brevity):

> 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      ***Stack Dump being sent to
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0058.txt 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.14 spid56      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 56 generated
>   fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is
>   terminating this process. 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   ******************************************************************************* 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   * BEGIN STACK DUMP: 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *   07/17/17 13:14:36 spid 56 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.14 spid56      * 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   Exception Address = 00007FF9DBE76564 Module(sqllang+00000000000C6564)
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *   Exception Code    = c0000005
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   Access Violation occurred reading address 0000000000000000 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.14 spid56      * Input Buffer 292 bytes - 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.14 spid56      *               DECLARE @memTable dbo.[Name]
>   INSERT INTO @memTable ([Nam 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *  e]) 
>   VALUES ('blah1'), ('blah3')    EXEC dbo.Test2 @memTable
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * sqlservr
>   00007FF6C6F30000  00007FF6C6F97FFF  00068000 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14
>   spid56      * ntdll                          00007FF9FE880000 
>   00007FF9FEA50FFF  001d1000 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   KERNEL32                       00007FF9FC7E0000  00007FF9FC88BFFF 
>   ...
>   00019000 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   xtp_v_8_907150277_184387255245303_1 00007FF9E7590000  00007FF9E75A8FFF
>   00019000 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * dbghelp
>   0000000077350000  00000000774E5FFF  00196000 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14
>   spid56      * 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     P1Home:
>   FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE:   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     P2Home:
>   0000000000000000:   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     P3Home:
>   0000007EF8A7AB80:  00007FF9DD881A70  000001CF0CAA8A70 
>   0000000000000000  000001CF31FE5C08  000001CF33A76040  000001CF125481A0
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     P4Home: 0000000000000040:
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *     P5Home: 000001CF3FD16080: 
>   00007FF9DB1D8C10  000001CF406CB248  000001CF3FD16CD8  0000000000000003
>   000001CF40080550  000001CF40080048   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *     P6Home: 00007FF9DB0585C9:  EE850FC085ED3345  20356E05F7000382  0E850F0010000000  0268858B48000383  890274C085480000  249C8D4CC68B4818
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * ContextFlags: 000000000010005F:
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA8:
>   ...
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rcx: 0000000000000000:
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rdx: 0000000000000000:
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rbx: 0000007EF8A7AB80: 
>   00007FF9DD881A70  000001CF0CAA8A70  0000000000000000  000001CF31FE5C08
>   000001CF33A76040  000001CF125481A0   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *        Rsp: 0000007EF8A7A570:  000001CF1E6CC370  000001CF35D1D450  000001CF35D1D500  000001CF33A76040  00007FF9DB0BCB10  0000000000000000
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rbp: 000001CF35D1D450: 
>   00007FF9DD80C7B0  000001CF00000001  000001CF35D1D500  0000000000000004
>   000001CF35D1D478  0000000000000000   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *        Rsi: 000001CF35D1D500:  00007FF9DD82C638  0000000000000001  000001CF0A59A060  0000000000000006  0000000000000000  000001CF35D1D5C0
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rdi: 00007FF9DD86FF28: 
>   00007FF9DC8968A0  00007FF9DC47C240  00007FF9DC47C250  00007FF9DC47C260
>   00007FF9DC62A170  00007FF9DD3D1D40   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *         R8: 0000000000000001:   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *         R9: 0000000000000038:   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   R10: 000001CF33A76040:  00007FF9DB1D8718  000001CF00000001 
>   0000000000002000  000001CF0000006E  000001CF0B9E0100  000001CF00000000
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        R11: 0000007EF8A7A520: 
>   0000000000000000  00007FF9DBE75499  000001CF33A50260  0000000000000000
>   000001CF33A50260  000001CF0CA8B480   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *        R12: 000001CF20580E30:  00007FF9DD80C7B0  0000000000000001  000001CF20580EE0  0000000000000002  000001CF20580E58  000001CF0CA83910
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        R13: 000001CF0CA8B480: 
>   00007FF9DD827FA8  000001CF00000001  000001CF0A59A060  000001CF00000008
>   0000000000000000  000001CF0A59A060   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   *        R14: 0000000000000000:   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        R15: 000001CF35D1D5C0:  00007FF9DD86F068  000001CF0A59A060 
>   000001CF00000000  0000000000000000  000001CF0CA82490  0000000000000000
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *        Rip: 00007FF9DBE76564: 
>   8B486850FF018B48  896052FFC88B4810  8B49000000D02484  718B48000001088F
>   85F8840FF6854838  84C748FE8B410036   2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56
>   * ******************************************************************************* 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      *
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2017-07-17 13:14:36.14 spid56      * Short Stack Dump 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.14 spid56      00007FF9DBE76564
>   ...
>   2017-07-17 13:14:36.16 spid56      00007FF9FE8E70D1
>   Module(ntdll+00000000000670D1) 2017-07-17 13:14:36.16 spid56
>   Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000001FA627823 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.87 spid56      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
>   External dump process returned no errors. 2017-07-17 13:14:36.87
>   Server      Error: 17310, Severity: 20, State: 1. 2017-07-17
>   13:14:36.87 Server      A user request from the session with SPID 56
>   generated a fatal exception. SQL Server is terminating this session.
>   Contact Product Support Services with the dump produced in the log
>   directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug: [Connect Bug Submission](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3137924)

A workaround is to not pass the memory-optimized table into the stored procedure. You can use it after that though.

**Fixed** in SQL Server 2017 CU1:

[Fix: Error when a stored procedure passes a memory-optimized table to an inline table-valued function in SQL Server 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4045329/fix-error-when-a-stored-procedure-passes-a-memory-optimized-table-to)